# Combining multiple docker images with multistage build not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I would like to create a Docker container image that has FFMPEG and NodeJs installed. I am trying a multistage build Dockerfile as follows using the [jrottenberg/ffmpeg](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrottenberg/ffmpeg) and [node:12](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) Docker images:

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg AS base

FROM node:12 as patch

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "--version" ]
```

This container displays the node version correctly as v12.20.2 (as expected). However, if I change the ENTRYPOINT to ffmpeg, I get an error. The modified Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM jrottenberg/ffmpeg AS base

FROM node:12 as patch

ENTRYPOINT [ "ffmpeg", "-version" ]
```

The error is:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec:
> "ffmpeg": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

I intend to use a NodeJS program that would spawn FFMPEG as a child process within the container. How do I get this to work?

I have also tried using `RUN apt-get install nodejs` instruction in the Dockerfile instead of the `FROM node:12`. That also does not work.

Comment: You can't use a multi-stage build to combine two images.  After the second `FROM` line you've started over completely from scratch.  A better approach would be to build an image `FROM node:buster` or another known Linux distribution base, then use the package manager to `apt-get install ffmpeg`.

Answer (score -1):

Update:

Incorporating feedback from @David Maze, the following dockerfile accomplished my original goal of NodeJs + FFMPEG on the image.

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN apk add ffmpeg

COPY ./app.js .

ENTRYPOINT node app.js
```

Although it is doesn't use a multistage build as I originally intended, it accomplished the purpose. The image size was also much smaller.

Comment: That seems What happens if dangerous the two `/usr/bin` to directories overlap me. with each other?

Comment: Seems dangerous to have two, overlapping /usr/bin directories.
Fixed your English for you ;